# Git merge conflict when there're only new lines on the remote

Tags: git

`git status` showed that my working was clean, then I ran `git pull` to get the latest code from remote repo, but I got a bunch of merge conflicts. I looked into those files, all have similar problem as below.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
======= 
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
>>>>>>> f3e4de1f6232c31ed9345138ec48cb55ad92c011
```

If I understand it correctly, this means that **a brand new line** was introduced in the remote repo, so why my git cannot successfully merge this? It sounds to me this is the simplest case, git merge will be totally useless if it cannot do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This sort of thing often happens because of chronology. For example, the line was added in a commit that preceded something in the local version.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case of formatting issue, your IDE formatted the code and the code in repo use different formatting. This issue is common when we are developing in different OS such as windows and Linux. So in order to avoid this please format the code which you have changed by selecting that portion only not the whole code. Hope this helps.